# Moleskine Pen+ convertible with Nnotebooks of Neo Smart Lab

Tags: pen, livescribe

I'm very new in using smartpens and I'm not sure in which forum I best post questions about it... 
I have a Moleskine Smart writing set but would like to make certain notes on single sheets ([like this ones](http://www.neosmartpen.nl/producten/ncode-pdf/?lang=en)) or use other notebooks than the PaperTablet from Moleskine.
I thought that this would be no problem, since the Pen+ uses the same Ncode technology as the smartpens from Neolab do. But this turned out to be wrong... My Moleskine Notes app doesn't recognise the paper from Neolab.
Do you have an idea, how I can use my Pen+ with single paper sheets and/or other notebooks which use the Ncode technology?

Answer (score 1):

Pen + from moleskine and neo notes work perfectly (I'm using that for 2 years) with that combination you can use all coded papers from neolab including the printed ones

Comment: I know that I am a little late but does it work inside the moleskine app? or do you use the neo notes app?

Comment: Does it work today? Today I tried to print paper on a printer, and the application from Moleskine did not react in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first part of your question, printing and using your own pages depends primarily on your printer's ability to print "fine enough") so the pen can read the Ncoded paper pattern.  That said, I believe a laser printer matching these NeoLab recommended criteria:

1. Use a color laser printer for printing Ncode PDF.
2. Install PCL/PS drivers to print exquisite Ncode. (Ask the printer manufacturer about PCL/PS driver.)
3. Use plain format for grayscale laser printers.

Regarding the second half of your question concerning off-the-shelf compatibility, I had a similar question and had difficulty finding the answer until I started looking at the Question/Answer of these pens and paper products. (e.g.,[Pen Q/A](https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/Tx284KCJIXYP09U/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_al_hza)).

Finally my sense of researching this "too much", is the biggest snag is for people to realize the communication protocols between pen and paper are different. In other words, the apps you choose (i.e., Neo's notes or Moleskine+ ***apps***) is the big decision.  Thus, I believe choosing how to interface with the pen is the biggest choice to make.

TOTAL DISCLOSURE: I have yet to purchase either of these products and my above statements are somewhat speculative and not COMPLETELY verified.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that, at least for the Moleskine Elipse + smart pen, the Moleskine Notes app was required, and this unfortunately limited my selection of notebooks to moleskine-branded ones. Neo Notes would not recognize and register the pen.

However, my experience with Neo Studio is that it recognizes both NeoLab ncode and Moleskine-branded ncode notebooks.